# "Who washes the washer" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

The machine that washes my clothes has somehow itself become unclean.  How to clean it is a question for some other forum, but I am reminded of the saying "Quis custodiet ipsos custodes".

How would I say in Latin "who washes the washer?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quis lavabit ipsam lavatoriam (machinam)?**

Firstly, "to wash" is *lavare*. Note that the verb *custodiet* is in fact a future tense, so following that, we get here *lavabit*.

As for "washer", it can be translated as *machina lavatoria*, "washing machine". 
Given that it needs to be in the accusative as it is the direct object - this prevents ambiguity with respect to any inflection of [lavatorium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavatorium) - I think you can safely omit *machina* so as to better mimic the classic saying. Just like in Italian one says *lavatrice* without specifying *macchina*.

Finally, if you want to be really clear and include *machinam*, note that in Latin [word order is quite free](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/537/did-word-order-have-any-function-in-colloquial-latin), thus while *machinam lavatoriam* would be the usual order, I swapped the two words because I believe it sounds nicer.

Comment: Note that the machine is direct object, so it should be in the accusative.

Comment: @TKR: Oooops, in my defense it was 3 am here haha.

Comment: @TKR: I rewrote this all because you know, I should really not write answers late in the night. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Vincenzo already gave you the Latin for “washing machine,” but since you asked for the “washer,” I would like to suggest:

> Quis lavabit ipsum lavatorem?

OK, *lavator* is a word I made up, *but* it turns out it's [actually attested](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=lavator). (The only attestation is apparently in the *Philoxenus glossary*, an obscure Latin–Greek dictionary which probably dates back to late antiquity and survived in a single medieval manuscript, so that's not very reassuring, but in any event the word is regularly formed and everybody should understand it immediately.)

Comment: Or maybe an earlier form [lotor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lotor), thus _Quis lavabit ipsos lotores?_